# How Can I Create Expandable Columns in HTML email?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am working on a two column HTML email design and using the sidebar style as a base (found here : http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php ). My problem here is that I can't find a way to make the text column expand to full width when the content on the right side ends. So far no matter what I do I end up with a giant text column on the left and blank space on the right once the sidebar stuff is over. How can get the left column to expand to full with below the sidebar? Obviously its a responsive template and all CSS needs to be inline (because Gmail sucks and wont read `<style>` tags)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Gmail is the least of your worries... there are __far worse__ email clients out there still being used.

Comment: @FDL Like Outlook, for some bizarre reason they're still using the Word rendering engine :)

Comment: Post code & screenshot please. We can't help troubleshoot without seeing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fully do what you are asking, which I assume is expanding your text-containing `<td>` so text flows fluidly into the free space after the sidebar stops. `<td>` columns are always the same width in every row, unless you set the colspan (html) attribute on them. So, you'll have to just make a new row with `colspan=2` on the td and split your text as close as possible to where the sidebar ends.

Answer (score 0):

In theory the code below could work. No inline CSS necessary.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">
        <table width="70" align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#00CCCC">
                    <br>
                    <strong>Sidebar</strong>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Elit wayfarers organic single-origin coffee pour-over tote bag. Sustainable Vice blog tattooed, fap twee ea church-key 3 wolf moon quinoa nisi Banksy hashtag. High Life biodiesel sustainable fanny pack. Pop-up meggings photo booth master cleanse in, readymade Echo Park laboris wayfarers cardigan pickled chillwave quis yr. Gastropub pug farm-to-table slow-carb, nostrud Cosby sweater magna kitsch officia gluten-free shabby chic voluptate cardigan actually. Culpa keytar whatever aliqua nisi Neutra. Messenger bag aesthetic asymmetrical, mumblecore disrupt chillwave swag.
        <br><br>
        Austin et street art, semiotics salvia nisi non velit fugiat cornhole laborum freegan polaroid. Trust fund bicycle rights Bushwick, adipisicing twee meh aliquip hoodie irony. Consectetur gastropub flexitarian, art party id Marfa meggings blog freegan banjo chillwave sunt gentrify post-ironic American Apparel. Biodiesel PBR&B swag tote bag stumptown exercitation Tonx, shabby chic consectetur locavore Godard quis. Occaecat VHS Helvetica pop-up synth, accusamus Pitchfork. Chia elit et nihil, yr literally roof party Odd Future PBR&B sartorial duis synth reprehenderit chillwave. Banksy jean shorts chillwave, seitan ex Echo Park PBR Pinterest sriracha forage lo-fi asymmetrical.
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```